# Can I determine the order of validation error messages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the order of validation messages to go in the same order as they do on our form.

We have three classes:

```
class User
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pledges
end

class Pledge
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
  validates_presence_of :pledgor_surname
end

class Company
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

In one form, we potentially have to take attributes for all three, so we get params like the following:

```
{"pledges_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"pledgor_surname"=>"",
     "id"=>"230",
     "companies_attributes"=>
      {"0"=>
        {"id"=>"125", 
         "name"=>""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I call `@user.update(params)`, it fails validation as I'd expect. But the `errors#full_messages` list looks like this:

```
["Company name can't be blank", "Pledgor surname can't be blank"]`
```

And the errors appear on the page in the same order.

Short of hacking the messages object, is there a way to tell Rails which order to place the messages in, or at least which of pledgor errors and company errors should go first?

Comment: the #full_messages turns the errors into an array, but before that they are in a hash-like object (see the section on `errors[]` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview-errors)). So you could use `errors.values_at(:name, :surname).flatten` to get the errors in the same order as the keys given.

Comment: Note that this is the really old Rails 3.x style of validation. Rails 4+ uses `validates :pledgor_surname, presence: true` as per the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are returned in a hash and hashes do not provide reliable ordering. This could be overridden, which is typically done by adding files to the lib folder and specifying your overrides in the rails config.

**Edit** According to the comment below since Ruby 1.9.3, hashes are actually ordered, so ignore what I said.

Comment: you can extract the values of a hash in a specific order. What exactly are you proposing that @Arepo "overrides"?

Comment: Additionally `Hash` is reliably ordered since 1.9.3

Comment: Did not know that, thanks for the information, I had just recently been working with Go where it is intentionally shuffled to prevent anyone confusing it for being ordered. I will update my answer or remove it if possible.